# Network timeout using node.js client at about 5 seconds

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Note, this question was previously very different. This is now the real issue. Which is...

When making a call to executeStoredProcedure() using the [node.js client](http://dl.windowsazure.com/documentDB/nodedocs/DocumentClient.html#executeStoredProcedure) I get a 408 code, RequestTimeout and I get no data back from the sproc's "body". This seems to occur at about 5 seconds, but when I time bound things from inside the sproc itself, any value over say 700 milliseconds causes me to get a network timeout (although I don't see it until about 5 seconds have passed).

Note, I can have longer running sprocs with read operations. This only seems to occur when I have a lot of createDocument() operations, so I don't think it's on the client side. I think something is happening on the server side.

It's still possible that my original thought is true and I'm not getting a false back from a createDocument() call which causes my sproc to keep running past its timeout and that's what's causing the 408.

Here is the time limited version of my create documents sproc

```
generateData = function(memo) {
  var collection, collectionLink, nowTime, row, startTime, timeout;
  if ((memo != null ? memo.remaining : void 0) == null) {
    throw new Error('generateData must be called with an object containing a `remaining` field.');
  }
  if (memo.totalCount == null) {
    memo.totalCount = 0;
  }
  memo.countForThisRun = 0;
  timeout = memo.timeout || 600; // Works at 600. Fails at 800.
  startTime = new Date();
  memo.stillTime = true;
  collection = getContext().getCollection();
  collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
  memo.stillQueueing = true;
  while (memo.remaining > 0 && memo.stillQueueing && memo.stillTime) {
    row = {
      a: 1,
      b: 2
    };
    getContext().getResponse().setBody(memo);
    memo.stillQueueing = collection.createDocument(collectionLink, row);
    if (memo.stillQueueing) {
      memo.remaining--;
      memo.countForThisRun++;
      memo.totalCount++;
    }
    nowTime = new Date();
    memo.nowTime = nowTime;
    memo.startTime = startTime;
    memo.stillTime = (nowTime - startTime) < timeout;
    if (memo.stillTime) {
      memo.continuation = null;
    } else {
      memo.continuation = 'Value does not matter';
    }
  }
  getContext().getResponse().setBody(memo);
  return memo;
};
```

Comment: Mind sharing the compiled JavaScript? I'd like to repo

Comment: I added the compiled JavaScript

Comment: Actually, I am now not sure if I get a false or not but looking at the code, if I get a false, the sproc terminates immediately after that and it still gets blacklisted.

Comment: I'm not seeing any red flags... Can you share your sample inputs for memo? I'd to profile the sproc execution.

Comment: OK, now I think the problem is that I'm getting a network timeout after about 5 seconds. I was not changing the default which in looking at the code appears to be 60 seconds. Is there another timeout provided by node.js that needs be overridden?

Comment: I poked at the network timeout issue and I don't believe it's a client side timeout, because I only seem to have this problem with sprocs that call createDocuments. I'm back to thinking that I never get a false returned from a call to createDocuments as the primary problem.

Comment: Note, this is also the first time that I'm using an S3 pricing tier, but that should have fewer restrictions not more.

Comment: Let's chat over e-mail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stored procedure above queues document creates in a while loop until the API returns `false`.

Keep in mind that `createDocument()` is an asynchronous method. The boolean returned represents whether it is time to wrap up execution right there and then. The return value isn't "smart" enough to estimate and account for how much time the async call will take; so it can't be used for queueing a bunch of calls in a while() loop.

As a result, the stored procedure above doesn't terminate gracefully when the boolean returns `false` because it has a bunch of createDocument() calls that are still running. The end result is a timeout (which eventually leads to blacklisting on repeated attempts).

In short, avoid this pattern:

```
while (stillQueueing) {
  stillQueueing = collection.createDocument(collectionLink, row);
}
```

Instead, you should use the callback for control flow. Here is the refactored code:

```
function(memo) {
  var collection = getContext().getCollection();
  var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
  var row = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
  };

  if ((memo != null ? memo.remaining : void 0) == null) {
    throw new Error('generateData must be called with an object containing a `remaining` field.');
  }
  if (memo.totalCount == null) {
    memo.totalCount = 0;
  }
  memo.countForThisRun = 0;

  createMemo();

  function createMemo() {
    var isAccepted = collection.createDocument(collectionLink, row, function(err, createdDoc) {
      if (err) throw err;

      memo.remaining--;
      memo.countForThisRun++;
      memo.totalCount++;

      if (memo.remaining > 0) {
        createMemo();
      } else {
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(memo);
      }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) {
      getContext().getResponse().setBody(memo);
    }
  }
};
```